# How to Display Slider Value In The TextArea

Tags: javascript

Hi I would like to display the sliders selected value displays in the text are when button is pressed.

The code needs to be pure javascript

i have manage to display the selected data in the console but i have no idea about how to display that data into text area.

```js
function execute() {
  var textsize = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
  console.log(textsize);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="execute();">Button</button>
<div id="textsizeslider" class="slidecontainer">
  Text Size: <input type="range" min="10" max="40" value="20" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
<textarea name="printerInstructions" id="printerInstructions" rows="8"></textarea>
```

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: Also try: `document.getElementById("printerInstructions").innerHTML = textsize;`

Answer (score 0):

To do this you simply need to refer to your textbox in your javascript code.

You can do this by doing

`document.getElementById('printerInstructions')`

This will refer to your textbox/textarea in your HTML. Thus, to change its value, you can use its `.value` attribute and set it equal to the `textsize`.

See working example below:

```js
function execute() {
  var textsize = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
  document.getElementById('printerInstructions').value = textsize;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="execute();">Button</button> </div>

<div id="textsizeslider" class="slidecontainer">
  Text Size: <input type="range" min="10" max="40" value="20" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>

<textarea name="printerInstructions" id="printerInstructions" rows="8"></textarea>
```

For "live" changes to your textbox as you slide you can add the `oninput` event to your slider to trigger your `execute` function everytime you slide your slider:

```js
function execute(textsize) {
  document.getElementById('printerInstructions').value = textsize;
}
```

```html
<div id="textsizeslider" class="slidecontainer">
  Text Size: <input oninput="execute(this.value)" type="range" min="10" max="40" value="20" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>

<textarea name="printerInstructions" id="printerInstructions" rows="8"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just equate the textarea value to the slider value

```js
function execute()
    { 
var textsize = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
document.getElementById("printerInstructions").value=textsize
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="execute();">Button</button> </div>


 <div id="textsizeslider" class="slidecontainer">

            Text Size: <input type="range" min="10" max="40" value="20" class="slider" id="myRange">
      </div>

  <textarea name="printerInstructions" id="printerInstructions" rows="8">

    </textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54253666/6808474) [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54253675/6808474). If you need to see the change the moment it is updated, you can use event handler and update it.

```js
document.getElementById('printerInstructions').value = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
document.getElementById("myRange").addEventListener('change', () => {
  document.getElementById('printerInstructions').value = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
});
```

```html
<div id="textsizeslider" class="slidecontainer">
  Text Size: <input type="range" min="10" max="40" value="20" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
<textarea name="printerInstructions" id="printerInstructions" rows="8"></textarea>
```